# Fill empty space between two DIV elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[image]
I am sorry that I am so bad at explanation.
I am using responsive grid from http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ and using 3 column style.

What I want to achieve is pretty much shown in the image. The order by which DIV elements are generated is labeled. The problem here is that after 1 , 2 , 3 are generated 4 should go to the place arrows point. I dont mind even 6 going there, but the place should be filled.

Div elements are generated using Database

```
<div class="section group">
<div class='col span_2_of_6 classifyGroup' style="height:50px;">
    <h3 class='classifyHeading'>BEVERAGES</h3>
</div>
<div class='col span_2_of_6 classifyGroup' style="height:75px;">
    <h3 class='classifyHeading'>salads</h3>
</div>
<div class="section group">
```

I have uploaded the site to [here](http://yoursitename.web44.net/buruzu2014/index2.php?Beverages=BEVERAGES&Salad=SALAD&Rice=RICE&Roshi=ROSHI&Pasta=PASTA&Noodles/Pasta=NOODLES/PASTA&Chicken=CHICKEN&Beef=BEEF)

Comment: +1 for adding screenshot.

Comment: can you give your working link here or css

Comment: This is using floating elements, that's the expected result then. On modern browsers, it should use CSS columns like here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Chkz/

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @HashirAzad http://yoursitename.web44.net/buruzu2014/index2.php?Beverages=BEVERAGES&Salad=SALAD&Rice=RICE&Roshi=ROSHI&Pasta=PASTA&Noodles/Pasta=NOODLES/PASTA&Chicken=CHICKEN&Beef=BEEF

Comment: @A.Wolff please post that as an answer...

Comment: @TJ sorry but i can provide the whole page html ?

Comment: Sounds like a case for **Masonry** ( http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried the script before posting here, but my Javascript ability su#ks. I mean like the page layout changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add `-webkit-column-count: 3;` to parent section container
2. change you div's class `span_2_of_6` to `span_1_of_1`
3. add `width:100%;margin-left:0 important;` to class `.col`

Comment: Add

overflow: hidden;
break-inside: avoid-column;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;

and works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using floating elements, that's not designed for result you are expecting.
On modern browsers, you should use `CSS multiple-columns` like here:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Chkz/)

See article on [CSS trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/)
See supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=columns

To support older browsers as IE8/9, you should use isotope jQuery plugin: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/